# How do I switch to the Oxygen GTK feature in KDE?

Tags: kde

I want to try the new oxygen to gtk port for kde 4.6. But I'm not sure how to enable it. I currently use qtcurve for gtk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what distribution you are using, but on my Kubuntu 11.04 machines I just enable it using the **System Settings / Application Appearance / GTK+ Appearance** tab in the usual way, choosing **Oxygen-Molecule** from the **Widget style** dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the question correctly, you want to use a GTK theme provided by KDE. All you have to do is to modify **~/.gtkrc-2.0** (there are a few applications allowing you to select the theme in a GUI, i.e. lxappearance) and start an application using GTK.

Comment: so kde has no built in way of enabling?

Comment: I'm afraid KDE doesn't allow you to change your GTK theme (at least not that I know of).

Answer (score 0):

I believe merely having the Oxygen GTK Theme is not enough to enable it. There is a seperate KCM module for KDE which permits KDE, infecting shall we call it, GTK applications with its presence.

When installed, ( when it works that is, its not working for me *right now* :( ) it appears in the KDE SystemSettings in the "Application Appearance" control, and lets you

1. Set GTK Font sizes ( either to an arbitrary size, or "match KDE" )
2. Set GTK ColourScheme ( either to an arbitrary pallete, or "match KDE")
3. Set GTK Widget Set ( either an arbitrary GTK theme, or the oxygen one )

On Gentoo, this module is available as kde-misc/kcm_gtk, and the metadata says the homepage is :  http://gtk-qt.ecs.soton.ac.uk , however, that just gives me a dead site :/